# git rebase: fixup commits but use latest message

Tags: git, rebase

I know how to squash commits together and drop messages:

```
pick A do thing
pick B debug
fixup C more debugging
pick D do another thing
```

This will result in 3 commits, with the 2 debugging commits squashed together into one, with the message "debug".  However, I wanted to know if there is a simple way to `fixup` commits, but use the LATEST message, rather than the earliest.  For example:

```
p A do thing
p B debug 1
f C debug 2
f D fix bug. #also remove debug statements
```

By running the above, I'll end up with a single commit that fixes the bug, and there will be no remnants of the debug statements.  The issue is that that commit will have a comment of "debug 1".  I'd like it to have the message of "fix bug". I know that I can `reword` the commit, but that opens the editor, and forces me to retype the commit message.  I've tried rewording and copying the message inside the rebase file, but when the `reword` editor opens, it still has the old message.

Is it possible to either `fixup` commits but use the latest message, or to modify the commit messages inside the rebase editor, without having to have it open the editor for each individual commit I want to `reword`?

Comment: No, that goes against the explicit definition of `fixup`. You can use `squash`, and just remove all commit messages except for the last one (that you want to keep)

Comment: @Amit that basically results in the same thing. I have to open the editor for each commit and change the message manually

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you really have a choice. However, instead of using fixup & reword, you can use squash

```
p A do thing
p B debug 1
s C debug 2
s D fix bug. #also remove debug statements
```

You'll get the editor open with the three first commits messages that you can edit.

## Without rebase

You can do it otherwise by using `reset`.

```
# To clean the workspace before by saving the state
git stash
git reset --soft HEAD~3
# To restore the saved state before the reset operation
git commit -am 'fix bug'
git stash pop
```

With this solution the editor won't open

Answer (score 1):

Change your todo list at the beginning of rebase to reverse the order of commits to fixup:

```
pick A do thing
pick C more debugging
fixup B debug
pick D do another thing
```

Comment: That seems likely to cause conflicts. For example in the case I described, the commit that removes the debug lines would come before the commits that add them

Comment: What you want cannot be easily done, you have to do some manual work anyway. You just have to decide in what case there is less labour.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the latest Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) could help, considering "`rebase -i`" is getting enhanced with new options.

See [commit 2c0aa2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c0aa2ce2efcac181801957d8105c7007db5faf7), [commit bae5b4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bae5b4aea523388faedd3b850c862fe45198c6b2), [commit 1d410cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d410cd8c25978c1591a7d35c9077745146c6129), [commit 9e3cebd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e3cebd97cbd47909e683e617d5ffa2781f0adaa), [commit 71ee81c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71ee81cd9eea308aa72d41fed3ef1cd40b4cb89a), [commit ae70e34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae70e34f234e675878a34b0bd76c43ffe79b95af) (29 Jan 2021) by [Charvi Mendiratta (`charvi-077`)](https://github.com/charvi-077).
See [commit 7cdb968](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cdb9682545d7865e832d092f900a8037898e907) (29 Jan 2021), and [commit 498bb5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/498bb5b82e78ddf880ab8516d4e6ac4fc5f9b215), [commit eab0df0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eab0df0e5b96ea8ca60f030dd8c5f6e5926988de) (19 Jan 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ce4296c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce4296cf2b6f66d8717e8c3237c9b4be42fb2a1b), 26 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e3cebd97cbd47909e683e617d5ffa2781f0adaa): add `fixup [-C | -c]` command
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Charvi Mendiratta</sup>

> Add options to `fixup` command to fixup both the commit contents and message.
>
> - `fixup -C` command is used to replace the original commit message and
> - `fixup -c`, additionally allows to edit the commit message.

Combined with:

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bae5b4aea523388faedd3b850c862fe45198c6b2): teach `--autosquash` to work with `amend!`
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Charvi Mendiratta</sup>

> If the commit subject starts with "`amend!`" then rearrange it like a "`fixup!`" commit and replace `pick` command with **`fixup -C` command, which is used to fixup up the content if any and replaces the original commit message with `amend!` commit's message.**

The [`git rebase -i` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa153c1cd7a84accc83e97723af85cf0ab3869e7/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L886-L899) now reads:

> If you want to fold two or more commits into one, replace the command
> "`pick`" for the second and subsequent commits with "`squash`" or "`fixup`".
>
> If the commits had different authors, the folded commit will be
> attributed to the author of the first commit.
>
> The suggested commit message for the folded commit is the concatenation of the first
> commit's message with those identified by "`squash`" commands, omitting the
> messages of commits identified by "`fixup`" commands, unless "`fixup -c`"
> is used.
> In that case the suggested commit message is only the message of the "`fixup -c`" commit, and an editor is opened allowing you to edit the message.
> The contents (patch) of the "`fixup -c`" commit are still
> incorporated into the folded commit.
> If there is more than one "`fixup -c`" commit, the message from the final one is used.
>
> You can also use "`fixup -C`" to get the same behavior as "`fixup -c`" except without opening an editor.

[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f07871d302c32777de25b3fde3c621be3b2e32c3/rebase-interactive.c#L47-L50) includes (from [commit f07871d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f07871d302c32777de25b3fde3c621be3b2e32c3)):

> ### `f`, `fixup [-C | -c] <commit>`
>
> Like "`squash`" but keep only the previous commit's log message, unless `-C` is used, in which case keep only this commit's message;
> `-c` is same as `-C` but opens the editor\n"

---

"[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dc154c39f7303baaf6cad8982a814b28a3a2027a/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L501)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> can mistakenly attempt to apply a `fixup` to a commit itself, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit 3e367a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e367a5f2f53f19130b90a97c3e2668eca3461ae) (24 Sep 2022) by [Johannes Altmanninger (`krobelus`)](https://github.com/krobelus).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc154c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc154c39f7303baaf6cad8982a814b28a3a2027a), 10 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e367a5f2f53f19130b90a97c3e2668eca3461ae): avoid dropping fixup commit that targets self via commit-ish
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Erik Cervin Edin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Altmanninger</sup>

> Commit [68d5d03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68d5d03bc49a073be3b0e14b22d30d70e7ae686d) ("`rebase`: teach `--autosquash` to match on sha1 in addition to message", 2010-11-04, Git v1.7.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbcf0a6981687b31635d806f45e77188c54b7cfc)) taught autosquash to recognize subjects like "fixup! 7a235b" where 7a235b is an OID-prefix.
> It actually did more than advertised: 7a235b can be an arbitrary commit-ish (as long as it's not trailed by spaces).
>
> Accidental(?) use of this secret feature revealed a bug where we would silently drop a fixup commit.
> The bug can also be triggered when using an OID-prefix but that's unlikely in practice.
>
> Let the commit with subject "`fixup! main`" be the tip of the "`main`" branch.
> When computing the fixup target for this commit, we find the commit itself.
> This is wrong because, by definition, a fixup target must be an earlier commit in the todo list.
> We wrongly find the current commit because we added it to the todo list prematurely.
> Avoid these fixup-cycles by only adding the current commit to the todo list after we have finished looking for the fixup target.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the best methodology I found for this was to simply edit the rebase  file after running "git rebase --interactive --autosquash" and replace "fixup" with "squash" (or simply "s").

This will concatenate the two commit messages and allow you to edit the final message.